# NPM Private Modules: How can I install my private modules on a AWS Beanstalk instance?

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, npm-private-modules

NPM Private Modules look great, but I'm not sure how to install them on an AWS Beanstalk instance.

Is there any literature published on this?

Also, on the default Node.js configuration Beanstalk uses npm version 2.7.4.  Will this be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, then add your repository (keys etc.) into the config in startup commands of elastic-beanstalk `.ebextensions/00-my-tasks.config`:

```
container_commands:
  00-my-task:
    command: echo "some config" >> /etc/config_of_npm
```

Idk, how exactly this works for npm, but it's possible to do that with private docker repositories. You can basically "hack" there anything, including update of some utilities if needed. I hope it helps you.